# static import not working in lombok builder in intelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lombok

I am using Lombok in IntelliJ. Though everything else is working fine when I try to do the static import of the Lombok builder, IntelliJ build project doesn't find the builder class. If you don't use static import, it works fine.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code which is not working and also the versions of IntelliJ, lombok and lombok plugin you use?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is a known bug, and not something that's easy to fix. Static imports are resolved before the annotation processors are run. This is a problem in javac, not lombok.

Disclosure: I am a lombok developer.

Comment: The relevant open issue for this seems to be https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/2044

Comment: I just had a similar problem. I converted some hand written Builder to lombok and the project lombok refused to generate any sources. Turns out Someone had used `import static` to import the generated builder class. It's unnecessary, but it worked with the hand-written class. It took me quite a few hours to figure out that one.

Comment: Still a bug 6 years later in Java 17 (and lombok 1.18.30). This was fun to debug.

Answer (score -2):

I ran into this error, after I added the lombok dependancy.

I solved this by:

1. Installing the intellij lombok plugin.

2. Enabling annotation processing at "Settings > Build > Compiler > Annotation Processors"

3. Restart IDE.

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution is misleading. The one at the top from @Roel Spilker is the correct one.