# Lombok is not being recognized in LibGDX project

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, libgdx, lombok

I'm working on libGDX project and I want to use Lombok. I followed [this short tutorial](https://github.com/drusin/LibgdxLombokTest) about using lombok in libGDX projects but unfortunately it does not working.

Situation looks like this - IntelliJ is recognizing lombok and does not complaining about get/set methods, but when I want to run project (using gradle) there's java compiler error like

> error: cannot find symbol static builder
>
> error: cannot find symbol method setBoardSize(float a, float b)

so basically Lombok is not being recognized.

Usually the advice is to set '*enable annotation processing*' in the IntelliJ but I tried without a success - I also tried reinstalling the Lombok plugin, changing Lombok version to 1.18.8, adding to the build.gradle android section

> annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.6"

but nothing fixed the issue. I also believe that it is not issue of IntelliJ because when I'm trying to run project from gradle command line using

> gradlew desktop:run

it is not working and I have the same stacktrace

Did anyone have the same issue? How to resolve this?

I'm attaching my *build.gradle* underneath

```
buildscript {


    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.wisepersist:gwt-gradle-plugin:1.0.6'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'


    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "light-game"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.8'
        roboVMVersion = '2.3.3'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.8.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "war"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        providedCompile "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.6"
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:$box2DLightsVersion"
        provided "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.6"
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "war"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:$box2DLightsVersion"
        providedCompile "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.6"
    }
}

project(":html") {
    apply plugin: "gwt"
    apply plugin: "war"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:$box2DLightsVersion:sources"

    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

Comment: have you also added the lombok plugin?

Comment: Do you mean IntelliJ plugin? Yes I installed it

Comment: And it seems to be working - IntelliJ is not complaining, I have autocompletion etc

Comment: I would expect it to "not complain" when you have the dependency on it's own. I don't think you would need the plugin for that

Comment: Anyway it is not working neither in IntelliJ nor command line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh - so finally I found the issue and it was quite surprising. It turned out that my configuration was fine, IntelliJ was fine but Lombok itself has an issue I was not aware about - this issue is **static import of builder() method**, which completely messes up the bytecode of compiled classes and causes issues like mine

Basically all I had to do was to remove such imports as

```
import static com.antkowicz.project.MyClass.builder;

public MyClass getMyClass() {
    return builder().build();
}
```

and instead of this use

```
import static com.antkowicz.project.MyClass;

public MyClass getMyClass() {
    return MyClass.builder().build();
}
```

Seems that this issue is well known but not going to be resolved soon (or ever) and it's nothing trivial - so basically the only thing we can do is to ommit static imports with Lombok (at least *builder()*) :)

A few links beneath about this topic:

- [static import not working in lombok builder in intelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47674264/static-import-not-working-in-lombok-builder-in-intellij)
- https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/2044
- https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1326
- https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/979