# How to model constructors which use fewer arguments in lombok

Tags: java, lombok

How to model this in Lombok, constructors which take lesser arguments and supporting get/set for transient methods. How to tweak the following definitions

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class SalaryRange {

    private Integer from;

    private Integer to; 

    private transient String displayName;

    private SalaryRange() {
    }   

    private SalaryRange(Integer from) {
        this(from, null);
    }   

    private SalaryRange(Integer from, Integer to) {
        this(from, to, null);
    }   

    private SalaryRange(Integer from, Integer to, String displayName) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to; 
        this.displayName = displayName;
    } 

..
}
```

Comment: how about "manually add them"? let's say there is a "partially constructor", how would they know for which variables to provide a parameter, and how would it be clear to the using classes which parameters they would be adding?

Comment: don't use lombok in that case.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a `Builder` and `NoArgsConstructor`

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
public class SalaryRange {
    private Integer from;
    private Integer to; 
    private transient String displayName;
}
```

and then

```
SalaryRange range = SalaryRange.builder().from(1).to(2).build();
```

Documentation:

- [Project Lombok Builder](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder)

---

One additional notice - when using `@Builder` **do not static import** Builder class - there is a bug that, as far as I know, is not fixed yet

- [static import not working in lombok builder in intelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47674264/static-import-not-working-in-lombok-builder-in-intellij)

Comment: So do you really need a Builder if you have to support setting few members from your class definition. I don't want them to set displayName, it would be internally set from within the class itself, i.e the list of valid SalaryRanges will be from within the class

Comment: then the `displayName` field should be marked `final` - you can also create your own private constructor and call it wherever you want (Builder's `build` method can be also overwritten - https://rusyasoft.github.io/java,%20lombok/2020/02/14/Overriding-build-setter-lombok-builder/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Lombok provide that much flexibility with constructor annotation. 2 approaches may help:

1. Use `@RequiredArgsConstructor`, which takes in all final variables.

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class SalaryRange {

    private final Integer from;

    private final Integer to; 

    private transient String displayName;

}
```

2. Use `@Builder` to achieve more flexibility. However, you may still need `@NoArgsConstructor` `@AllArgsConstructor` sometimes for serialization/deserialization by thirty party tools integration, e.g. spring rest, mybatis, etc. Just try it out and check logs.

Otherwise, just write constructor manually, intellij can generate constructor for you quickly by `command + N`

Answer (score 0):

You may keep constructors from below, the other two are generated by `@NoArgsConstructor` and `@AllArgsConstructor`, constructors are meant to build objects

```java
    private SalaryRange(Integer from) {
        this(from, null);
    }   

    private SalaryRange(Integer from, Integer to) {
        this(from, to, null);
    }
```

Another approach might be to combine `@Accessors` (experimental feature) with `@NoArgsConstructor` and `@AllArgsConstructor`

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Accessors(chain = true)
public class SalaryRange {
    private Integer from;
    private Integer to; 
    private transient String displayName;
}
```

```
SalaryRange salaryRange1 = new SalaryRange().setFrom(1).setTo(2);

SalaryRange salaryRange2 = new SalaryRange(1, 2, "somename");
```

You may use `@Accessors(chain = true, fluent = true)` to have fluent accessors if you don't require the `get` & `set` prefix

```
SalaryRange salaryRange1 = new SalaryRange().from(1).to(2);
```

PD: Builder pattern has downsides that might lead to an [Anti-Pattern](https://quinngil.com/2019/12/17/builders-as-an-antipattern/) and might hide a bad design, so be careful when you decide to use it. I think Builder pattern is overused in this scenario, we don't need to add extra complexity to build an object with three attributes.

- https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-accessors
- https://www.yegor256.com/2016/02/03/design-patterns-and-anti-patterns.html